# How to integrate Firebase mobile authentication with custom laravel - Mysql backend?

Tags: mysql, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use Firebase Mobile Auth to authenticate mobile phone clients, but I have an existing backend build with laravel and Mysql database with lots of functions. Is it possible to authenticate users with Firebase and then allow them to read and write data to the Mysql database securely? I mean I want the users to Authenticate using firebase then either store their data on my Mysql database or find a way to communicate from my laravel backend with firebase to authenticate users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You'll:

1. Sign-in the users with Firebase Authentication.
2. Get and pass their ID token from the client to the server over a secure connection.
3. Decode and verify the token on the server.
4. Check in your application code if that user is authorized to access the data they're trying to access.

The entire flow is also described in the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: So clients send ID Token in every HTTP requests made to our backend, and backend need to verify id token using Admin-SDK everytime right? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Correct. Note that you can keep a cache of the decoded tokens, so that you don't have to decode each token on each call, and can go straight to verifying the properties of the (already) decoded token. Some of he Firebase backend services do that.