# Correct way to handle email/password sign up, in addition to using Laravel Socialite for OAuth?

Tags: laravel, firebase-authentication, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite, laravel-authentication

I'm building an iOS app with Laravel backend.

I'm using Firebase Authentication to handle the following authentication types: Google, Apple, and email/password sign up.

I've set up Google and Apple sign up by utilizing Laravel Socialite, however it doesn't look like Socialite supports an email/password driver, so I can't use this code for email/password authentication:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'provider_name' => 'required|string|in:google,apple',
            'access_token' => 'required|string',
        ]);
 
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            Log::info($validator->errors());
            return;
        }

        $providerName = $request->input('provider_name');
        $token = $request->input('access_token');

        $providerUser = Socialite::driver($providerName)
            ->userFromToken($token);

        $user = User::where('provider_name', $providerName)
            ->where('provider_id', $providerUser->id)
            ->first();

        if ($user == null)
        {
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $providerUser->name;
            $user->email = $providerUser->email;
            $user->provider_name = $providerName;
            $user->provider_id = $providerUser->id;
            $user->save();
        }

        $token = $user
            ->createToken("token")
            ->accessToken;

        return response()->json([
            "status" => "success",
            "data" => [
                "token" => $token,
                "user" => $user
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

So what's the "right" way of ALSO handling email/password sign up?

I'm at the point where I've the user is signed in on the iOS app and the account has been created through Firebase. I just don't know what to do to actually pass the user data to the Laravel backend and handle authentication/tokens as I do with Google/Apple authentication.

Comment: At first glance I see no calls to Firebase in the code you shared. Can you clarify *how* you are using Firebase here?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The Firebase handling is done on the iOS side. What I'm doing is calling the my api and passing the provider name, provided by Firebase, and the access token to add records to my db and return the user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I came across one of your other posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794677/8463453. This makes sense to me but I'm a bit confused now. If I'm doing firebase authentication on the ios side, do I only need to verify the id token on the server side? For both OAuth and email/password auth? Do I need to be using Laravel Socialite at all? And if I wanted to keep a database of users, would I just retrieve the user on the server side using the id token, and the use the user data firebase provides to insert records into my user db?

Comment: What I currently have implemented is something along these lines: https://j8n.medium.com/laravel-implementing-social-auth-for-api-via-mobile-app-with-socialite-passport-30ff4a6fc4d

Comment: If the user signs in to the iOS app with Firebase, you can handle email+password sign-in there too. Then (no matter how they signed in), you can pass the ID token to your server and [verify it there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) to determine what user is making the call.